# Design generic interface for data object used throughout a service

Tags: java, generics, interface, architecture, java-8

Been migrating over some legacy code and I came across this.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CollectedData
{
    SkillResponse skills;
    TrendingResponse storyMatch;
    Map<String, String> slotData;
    Map<String, String> slotDataSecondSource;
    Boolean hasSlots;
    Boolean hasSlotsSecondSource;
    KnowledgeRequest request;
}
```

Since I've been using java 8 and accustomed to streams, I started to restructure this response class as ..

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CollectedData
{
    List<DataSupplierResponse> dataSupplierResponses;
    Metadata metadata;
}
```

Where DataSupplierResponse was to be a defined interface like so..

```
public interface DataSupplierResponse<T>
{
    DataSupplierType getDataSupplierType();

    T getSupplierResponse();
}
```

Implementation Example:

```
public class DataSupplierResponseImpl implements DataSupplierResponse<TrendingResponse>
{
    private TrendingResponse mTrendingResponse;

    public DataSupplierResponseImpl(
        TrendingResponse trendingResponse)
    {
        mTrendingResponse = trendingResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSupplierType getDataSupplierType()
    {
        return DataSupplierType.TRENDING_STORY;
    }

    @Override
    public TrendingResponse getSupplierResponse()
    {
        return mTrendingResponse;
    } 
}
```

The goal is to run certain predicates depending on the `CollectedData`.

```
Optional<DataSupplierResponse> first = data.getDataSupplierResponses().stream()
                .filter(res -> res.getDataSupplierType().equals(DataSupplierType.TRENDING_STORY))
                .findFirst();
```

This would need a cast in order to get the right object. It returns Object

```
TrendingResponse match = first.get().getSupplierResponse();
```

Thus when I started refactoring, I assumed to solve this issue of data being available by creating the generic interface that returns different data. To make this code work, I would have to cast the return object of getSupplierResponse which defeats the purpose of using generics. I need to make this Data Carrier object as clean and beautiful as possible for my own sake. Any ideas how I should structure these classes, and/or how to use generics to solve this problem.

EDIT: I know the StackOverflow community likes to enforce objective, concrete answers but where else to go to for design questions?

Comment: can you edit classes like `SkillResponse` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `List` in `CollectedData` also with generics. E.g:

```
List<DataSupplierResponse> dataSupplierResponse;
```

should actually be:

```
List<DataSupplierResponse<YourType>> dataSupplierResponse;
```

where `YourType` corresponds to the type of the response. That is because when using a [`RawType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) (a generic class without actually specifiying a generic) all Generic information for that class is eliminated. That's why it is returning `Object`s and you have to manually cast it.

Comment: 1+, OP added the generics in one part of the code, but not the other...

Comment: @Eugene exactly. though what I don't know is, if all elements in the list have the same return type. If they don't then the answer will be quite different and a lot more difficult

Comment: I did not go into the details of the question too much to be honest, so I'll trust you here

Answer (score 1):

Unless used in other places, I'd get rid of the `enumeration` type `DataSupplierType` as the `classes` `TrendingResponse` (and others) already provide a discrimination criteria.

*(Also keep in mind that `enums` are full `classes`)*

The perfect response to this would have you implement a basic type for your response, e.g:

```
interface Response {
    int getScore(); // implement in subclasses
    String getName(); // implement in subclasses
}

class TrendingResponse implements Response {}
class SkillResponse implements Response {}
class OtherResponse implements Response {}
```

but this is not strictly necessary.

At this point just a generic wrapper `class` would be enough (no need to have a base `interface` and extend it for each type of response):

```
class DataSupplierResponse<T extends Response>  {
    private T t;

    public DataSupplierResponse(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public T getSupplierResponse() {
        return this.t;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to call:

```
Optional<DataSupplierResponse<?>> first = data.responses
            .stream()
            .filter(response -> TrendingResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(response.getClass()))
            .findFirst();

first.ifPresent( o -> o.getSupplierResponse().getScore() );
```

or simply

```
Optional<?> first = data.responses
            .stream()
            .filter(response -> TrendingResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(response.getClass()))
            .map(r -> r::getSupplierResponse)
            .findFirst();
```

Even without the base interface `Response` (which is useful only for defining common behavior in your responses), your `class DataSupplierResponse<T>` wouldn't need the `enumeration` type.